# SASS: Override bootstrap's default primary, success, info ..etc colours

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am working in Visual Studio Code. I am using Gulp / Node to compile my SASS.

Things are working well, but for some reason I can't override this in Bootstrap:

```
$brand-primary:         darken(#428bca, 6.5%) !default; // #337ab7
$brand-success:         #5cb85c !default;
$brand-info:            #5bc0de !default;
$brand-warning:         #f0ad4e !default;
$brand-danger:          #d9534f !default;
```

In my own `_variable.scss` I have the following:

```
$brand-primary:         darken(#428bca, 6.5%)
$brand-success:         #0aa699;
$brand-info:            #1f3853;
$brand-warning:         #fbb05e;
$brand-danger:          #f35958;
$brand-grey:            #d1dade;
```

And I am ensuring that all my custom `.scss` comes **after** the bootstrap stuff is loaded, yet them custom colours of mine aren't showing!

Here is the structure of the partials:

**styles.scss**

> @import "../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
>
> @import "custom/myappstyles";

**myappstyles.scss**

> @import "modules/variables";
>
> @import "modules/mixins";
>
> @import "modules/layout";
>
> @import "modules/typography";
>
> @import "modules/forms";
>
> @import "modules/buttons";
>
> @import "modules/tables";
>
> @import "modules/navigation-sidebar";
>
> @import "modules/approval-sidebar";

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you write down your structure and imports?

**UPDATE: Try to put variables before bootstrap import.**

Comment: I think the structure and the imports are correct. With the !default its not important if they are before or after bootstrap. As you can read in the documentation.

Is there an compiling error (npm or gulp)?

EDIT: You just want to override the plain bootstrap colors which are not used on individial definitions, right? Then you have to put you variables before the bootstrap import. Because the variables will in this case overwritten before all bootstrap stuff is compiled.

Comment: hmm why must I do that? I thought SASS and CSS both worked on the rule that whatever comes later overrides what comes before (assuming selectors are same).

Comment: This is true, but all components of bootstrap are imported within this bootstrap import. That means, that all variables are compiled to values and after that you import your variables, but the bootstrap components are already build. So you overwriting the variables correctly but they are not user anywhere.